# Embeded computer F-RAM imaging

Tags: images, flash, embedded

Here is the situation:

I have an old ISA card type computer hooked up to controller card to drive a cutting machine. The manufacturer is not in business for the last 10 years, so support is zero.

[image: Computer]

It's storage device is failing, and it needs a replacement.

It has Intel 80486 CPU with modest amounts of RAM, running DOS 6.22. The problem is it does not use "standard" non-volatile storage, but flash based F-RAM, so replacing it with IDE storage is no trivial task. I've managed to start DOS and use FDD to transfer F-RAM contents to a hard drive and tried to run it inside of a virtual machine, after repairing the boot sectors. It starts DOS just fine, but not the app required for machine control. As it turns out there are parts of F-RAM not directly accessible for copying.

Next I tried running Norton Ghost from roughly 20-year old FDD, trying to create .GHO image of the entire F-RAM, but it simply does not show up inside Ghost.

So my next idea was to try and use available IDE interface to boot from and try to start another CLI OS, such as free DOS or linux without GUI, but BIOS has no option to boot from devices other than F-RAM.

When that did not work, I tried booting DOS from F-RAM, start GRUB from FDD, and try to chain-load another OS from IDE storage device, but that kinda blew up in my face, as I got all confused during this process... I'll try again when I clear my head...

I am running out of ideas here, so if there is anyone with some embedded computing experience PLEASE HELP ME!

Comment: From the size of the heatsink and the use of 72 pin, 32 bit SIMMs, this looks like a 486. If you want to boot linux, you should correctly identify the CPU type, as only 486 and newer is supported by some distros. I would follow the approach of booting Linux from the secondary IDE.

Comment: If it is a 486 here is a 486 cloning tool http://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=stable   However, I don't know if you can boot from it or not.  If you could get some kind of linux running you could use the **dd** tool most linux distros have.

Comment: Is it time for an upgrade yet? If I were in this circumstance professionally, or if it were in my personal setup, I would personally upgrade. If all the hardware is severely outdated, an upgrade is in order. This is not an opinion, it is just the way it is. VM's can emulate DOS if that is all you need.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, however the main problem is I can't directly boot from IDE device, BIOS is very limited.

Comment: As for an upgrade, it's not a case of pull computer out and put another in. The interfaces are very specialized, and I would still need the software from the old one. You have to understand that ROI on these machines has a much longer span outside of US, China or Germany.

Comment: If you add a secondary hard drive, you should use an imaging software that bypasses the BIOS and accesses the disk directly, as the BIOS does not seem to detect the disk. I woud still try to boot linux, for example [DSL](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/f/topic-3-26-11992-0.html), as the debug output from linux can give a lot of information.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. As it won't boot from any IDE or FDD device I will keep trying to chain-load linux and see where it goes from there. I'll let you know what happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,

After a long search for a solution I've dropped trying to replace the storage device. I've successfully copied software to several FDDs and created DOS virtual machine. I copied the software into the virtual drive and tried running it. It failed to start as part of the software is refusing to run on a hard drive that has a different serial number than original FRAM disk. I ended up hiring an engineer to download flash chip contents to a new ones and repair the FRAM board. I've got the idea from [here](http://spritesmods.com/?art=ftdinand) and he said he can pull something like that of.

It's now in use for several weeks without any of the problems surfacing again.